# Subject.create() Not working in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the Rails Console to create object instances of my models.

It is possible to create and save an instance to the database using the manual methods like so:

```
1.9.3p125 :003 > subject = Subject.new
 => #<Subject id: nil, name: nil, position: nil, visible: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p125 :004 > subject.name = "First Name"
 => "First Name" 
1.9.3p125 :005 > subject.position = 1
 => 1 
1.9.3p125 :006 > subject.visible = 'true'
 => "true" 
1.9.3p125 :007 > subject.save
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `subjects` (`created_at`, `name`, `position`, `updated_at`, `visible`) VALUES ('2012-06-21 13:28:35', 'First Name', 1, '2012-06-21 13:28:35', 1)
(20.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :008 > subject.id
 => 1 
1.9.3p125 :009 > subject.new_record?
 => false
```

I'm totally new to RoR so I've got no idea where to begin trouble shooting this error:

```
1.9.3p125 :010 > subject = Subject.create(:name => "Second name", :position => 2)
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name, position from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `new'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:44:in `create'
from (irb):10
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is my Subject model:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :name, :position
end
```

Thanks!

Things I've tried so far:

1. Exiting and reentering rails c.
2. Typing "reload!" into rails c
3. Reopening terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
attr_accessible :name, :position
```

To your `Subject` model so you can create this in one step. Its a thing of security. You can read about this here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

hf,..

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I opened the Subject model and added those two attributes to the list. Then I ran it in rails c and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @ninja08 Have you restarted the console/reloaded your models since making the change? If not, the console is still working with the old, unchanged versions. Running `reload!` in the console will usually update that stuff, but if it doesn't, exit and reopen the console.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Thanks, though neither of those options worked so far.

Comment: Is the error exactly the same as before you added attr_accessible?

Comment: Could you also post your subject.rb model?

Comment: ok I edited the original question to include the subject.rb contents

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem
the solution was to do it this way

`subject=Subject.create(name: 'Second name', position: 2)`

it works fine for me